# Why doesn't property have effect in ankhsvn?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, version-control, ankhsvn

I'm using Ankhsvn v2.0.6347.433 with VS.NET 2008.  It all works fine.  I've imported an .svnprops file from TotioseSVN.  This is done in Windows Explorer by right clicking the root svn folder, selecting the Subversion tab, properties, and import.  The import file filter starts off with svnprops.  After importing, the commit dialogue now has a place for entering in a bug ID.  When commiting through Tortoise, it works fine.  Viewing the log history shows a bug ID column with values.

AnkhSVN shows the Bug ID box as well.  However, even though a value is entered, that doesn't translate into the Bug ID column when viewing history.  AnkhSVN ignores the Bug ID value.

Here are the properties I'm entering into AnkhSVN Add/Edit Properties window followed by the value:

```
   bugtraq:label    Bug ID:
   bugtraq:message    Bug ID: %BUGID%
   bugtraq:url      http//bugserver/view.php?id=%BUGID%
   bugtraq:warnifnoissue    true
```

The URL makes the bug ID clickable from the comments.  It all works fine in TortioseSVN.  Any suggestions on how I can get AnkhSVN to do the same?  Is there a way to import the .svnprops through AnkhSVN?

Answer (score 2):

AnkhSVN doesn't have an issues column yet. We are working on that, but we can only implement a limited number of features at a time.

I'll update this answer when we have this feature implemented.

Feel free to open an [AnkhSVN UserVoice](http://ankhsvn.uservoice.com) suggestion on this topic.